# Mode dial fell off for Nikon D7000

Tags: nikon, dslr, nikon-d7000

After preparing myself to watch camera video, I dropped my nikon and the dial fell off. Is there a way of fixing this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flnx1.jpg

Comment: search on eBay for "mode dial replacement" and see if any of the suppliers have the part you require.

Comment: I am pretty confident that you can get this on Alibaba.com :-). I have seen the most esoteric camera stuff out there :-). E.g. try: "digital camera spare parts", and browse away...

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Send it to Nikon Factory Service and let them repair it.

If the dial is broken the only place you can get replacement parts is to send it to Nikon and let them repair it. Nikon no longer sells parts to third party repairers, other than a few external parts. I highly doubt you will be able to obtain a replacement part anywhere other than Nikon factory service.